# Лупа на весь сайт место указателя мыши

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Надо чтоб на весь сайт место указателя был лупа 100x100 и все на сайте внутри этого лупы(указателя) увеличить объекты 
типы этого 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

[Magnifier Glass](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_magnifier_glass.asp) Пример кода:

```js
function magnify(imgID, zoom) {
  var img, glass, w, h, bw;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  /*create magnifier glass:*/
  glass = document.createElement("DIV");
  glass.setAttribute("class", "img-magnifier-glass");
  /*insert magnifier glass:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(glass, img);
  /*set background properties for the magnifier glass:*/
  glass.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  glass.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  glass.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * zoom) + "px " + (img.height * zoom) + "px";
  bw = 3;
  w = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
  h = glass.offsetHeight / 2;
  /*execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image:*/
  glass.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  glass.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
  function moveMagnifier(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    x = pos.x;
    y = pos.y;
    /*prevent the magnifier glass from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - (w / zoom)) {x = img.width - (w / zoom);}
    if (x < w / zoom) {x = w / zoom;}
    if (y > img.height - (h / zoom)) {y = img.height - (h / zoom);}
    if (y < h / zoom) {y = h / zoom;}
    /*set the position of the magnifier glass:*/
    glass.style.left = (x - w) + "px";
    glass.style.top = (y - h) + "px";
    /*display what the magnifier glass "sees":*/
    glass.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + ((x * zoom) - w + bw) + "px -" + ((y * zoom) - h + bw) + "px";
  }
  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
}

magnify("myimage", 3);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-magnifier-container {
  position:relative;
}

.img-magnifier-glass {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: none;
  /*Set the size of the magnifier glass:*/
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Image Magnifier Glass</h1>

<p>Mouse over the image:</p>

<div class="img-magnifier-container">
  <img id="myimage" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_girl.jpg" width="600" height="400">
</div>

<p>Feel free to change the strength of the magnifier glass when initiating the magnify function.</p>
```

Comment: так только на картинке работает надо на весь сайт

Comment: Подправьте скрипт под свои нужды или тогда воспользуйтесь AnythingZoomer jQuery Plugin http://jsfiddle.net/34tmyj0w/